# Fonts , FontsWeight , Inter

Tags: flutter, dart, frontend, text, textfield

tengo un problema con una fontFamily Inter cuando esta en bold, o mas de w600, mis letras mayúscula A ,P,Q,R [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]aparece con un relleno.Inicialmente funcionaba bien, pero luego se creo una carpeta fonts por fuera, borre esta carpeta y deja una carpeta fonts  dentro de assets pero persiste el problema.

Comment: ¿Podrías redactar el mensaje de manera comprensible? ¿Qué quieres decir con "por fuera"?

Comment: Manuel, tengo la aplicación  con 2 tipos de fuentes, Inter y Montserrat, el relleno aparece solo con las letras A, P, Q y R... un equipo estaba desarrollando un modulo de la aplicacion y ellos habian creado una carpeta fonts en la raiz del proyecto  y habia otra carpeta fonts dentro de assets que esta estab enla raiz y al integrarlo sus cambios con los mios, ahi fue donde aprecio el incoveniente con esa fuente, la diseñadora me dijo que la cambiaramos por la DM Sans y sale el mismo relleno con esta.

Comment: aunque tambien tuve que actualizar la version de flutter, tambien creo que haya sido por eso, pero no se como solucionarlo.